# How to check for user info with PFQuery

Tags: swift, parse-platform

When a user signs up he/she is redirected to another view controller where they need to verify their phone number. I tried setting up a PFQuery to retrieve the user's code from Parse, and see if it matches with what was written in the verification text field, however, it always results in the user being redirected to the main view controller whether the code entered is right or wrong. I've also tried doing so with objectForKey (currentUser) and the query `if phoneCode != currentUser`, however the result is the same. What I am trying to do is check if the code entered is the correct one, and redirect the user to another view controller based on the response.

```
@IBAction func submitCodeTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()?.objectForKey("phoneVerification") as? NSValue
    let code = codeTextField.text
    let query = PFQuery(className: "User")
    let phoneCode = query.whereKey("phoneVerification", equalTo: code!)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil || objects != nil {
        //if phoneCode != currentUser{
            self.displayAlert2("Wrong Code", message: "This is not the code you were sent.")
        }else{
            let myUser:PFUser = PFUser.currentUser()!
            myUser.setObject(true, forKey: "phoneVerified")
            myUser.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success, error) -> Void in
                if error == nil{
                    print("Successfully set the object.")
                    self.displayAlert("Great!", message: "Your phone number has been verified!", error: nil)
                    let appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
                    appDelegate.buildUserInterface()
                }else{
                    //let loginVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("signInPage")
                    //self.navigationController?.pushViewController(loginVC!, animated: true)
                    print("Erreur")

                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: In your first if statement, error != nil means there is an error, objects != nil means the query successfully found objects(no error). Aren't these two statements conflict with each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first `if` statement, you are telling the server that if there is an error finding objects OR the query found some objects, then display the alert. But given that the user enters a wrong code, the query will return an empty array(**note that it won't return nil, it's an empty array**), but there won't be any errors, thus the `else` block is executed.

and since your "phoneVerification" is a Number, we need to covert the `codeTextField.text`into NSNumber:

```
let code = NSNumber(value:Int(codeTextField.text)!)
let query = PFQuery(className: "_User")
query.whereKey("phoneVerification", equalTo: code!)
```

you can change your first if statement to :

```
if ((error != nil && error! as! Bool) || objects?.count == 0) {
    //handle the error here.
}
```

Comment: Thank you. When applying the query if statement 'if error || !objects' I get the error "Optional type Bool cannot be used as a boolean, test for '!= nil' instead; and when I try without the query, I get the error "Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String?' and 'AnyObject?'" at the line 'code == codeOnServer'

Comment: @J.M is your value for key "phoneVerification" a string on your parse server?

Comment: Thanks. No the value for "phoneVerification" is a number.

Comment: @J.M You need to convert your textfield text and the number on your server into Int. See my edited answer, and tell me if that works.

Comment: I used the edited code but I still get the same errors.

Comment: @J.M Did you try with the query? I edited my if statement.

Comment: @J.M go with your original code, do that in a query, but remember to convert the textfield into NSNumber. see my answer pls.

Comment: I get an error at  'let code = NSNumber(value:Int(codeTextField.text)!)
' "Value of int not unwrapped; did you mean to use "!" or '?'"

Comment: @J.M try this: `let code = NSNumber(value:Int(codeTextField.text!)!)`

Comment: Yes, I've tried that, and I still get an error; this time "Argument labels '(value:)' do not match any available overloads.

Comment: @J.M How's that possible? are you using Swift3.0 in Xcode 8?

Comment: Okay...try `NSNumber(integer:Int(codeTextField.text!)!)`

Comment: Thanks, this error is fixed. However, now I get the error "Cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type NSNumber". When I remove the ! at "equalTo:code!), the build succeeds, but the user is redirected to the other view controller whether the code is right or wrong.

Comment: @J.M hmmm...strange. Did you change your if statement as I did? And what is "other view controller"? Can you tell me which block of code is executed?

Comment: Yes I changed my if statement as you did. The other view controller is set up in the app delegate, it's the code block " let appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
                    appDelegate.buildUserInterface()"

Comment: @J.M I think I found the problem. Inside your query block, if the user enters a wrong code, the server is returning an empty array, instead of nil. So, change your if statement into `if ((error != nil && error! as! Bool) || objects?.count == 0)`

Comment: @J.M I'm glad it works for you. And sorry for my lack of experience in Parse. :)

Answer (score 0):

change

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "User")
let phoneCode = query.whereKey("phoneVerification", equalTo: code!)
```

to

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "_User")
query.whereKey("phoneVerification", equalTo: code!)
```

If you want to fetch user using query, the name of user class is _User. That's why in your code, you always get objects is nil, so turns to else statement.

Also, I would suggest you to print objects and see what you get.

Comment: Thank you. I did that, but the result is still the same. I believe the problem starts from the part  "if error != nil || objects..." onwards

Comment: did you print and see what you get in objects? The way to debug this is try to look at why error is nil and objects is nil because you get result from else statement